Trying to create formula AGE formula for cases
I am trying to create a formula to verify the AGE of the cases. We respond to email and close the case after each response. When an email (reply) comes back it re-opens the case until we respond and close it back again. However, I want to know the age of the whole interaction since created to the last close. Keep in mind that I am new to this..(what am I doing wrong ?!) :

